# I need to get product collection by filter multiple category ids in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-collection, category-filter

I need to get product collection by filter multiple category ids.

Here is my code:

```
$catId = [2, 3, 5];
$productcollection = $objectmanager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$categoryProducts = $productcollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC')
    ->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $catId])
    ->addAttributeToFilter('color', ['in', $colorValues]);
```

But this code is not working.

Comment: Do you need sort the product by position in category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you pass the category ids array in `addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $cat_ids])` that's why the error occur. Just Replace my code with your's

```
$cat_ids = "2,3,5";
$productcollection = $objectmanager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$categoryProducts = $productcollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC')->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $cat_ids])->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('in',$colorvalues));
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thanks for reply. But this code is not working.

Comment: What was the error? Have you copy paste my code. It is working at my end.

Comment: Getting this error------>

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory::addAttributeToSelect()

Comment: Oh I got it, you have a problem in `$productcollection` object that's why it is unable to call `addAttributeToSelect('*')`. Check now I have updated my code.

Comment: I am passing the parent category ids in this array. But this is not checking the child category .It is the Only filtered on the specific id.

Comment: You have two options. If you want to use parent categories Ids so You have to fetch the child categories Ids from parent Ids before passing it to filters or You have to assign your products to parent categories so that it will fetch all the product related to that specific categories Ids. If my answer is helpful please mark  my answer correct and upvote my answer so it helps other as well.

Comment: Okay then how can filter child categories of parent in product collection.

Comment: First you have to fetch the child categories Ids from Parent Ids, there are so many codes available in internet after that pass the comma separated child categories Ids to this `addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $cat_ids])`. It will fetch all the product because `addaddCategoriesFilter` does not care about whether Ids are parents or childs it will fetch all product collection related to that categories Ids. I hope I clear your confusion

Comment: Thanks for your support. I solved my issue. :)

Comment: Welcome +1 for appreciation. Keep coding :) thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add the other attribute filter. I just check multiple category filter. It is working, I just Created object again after loading model collection.

```
$productcollection = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')->create();

$cat_ids = [179,109];

$categoryProducts = $productcollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$categoryProducts->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $cat_ids));

echo '<pre>';
echo count($categoryProducts);
//var_dump($categoryProducts);
foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
print_r($product->getData());
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected $_productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
}
public function getProductCollectionByCategories()
{
    $categories = [2,3,5];//category ids array
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categories]);
    return $collection;
}
```